# Edit 'affects verion/s' field

Tags: jira

I'd like to edit the `Affects Version/s` field of an issue in Jira, however, the field is not editable. I can see the field, but the `None` value cannot be changed.

From what I've found, this is commonly caused by the lack of version(s) in the project. There are existing versions in my project (in various states too).

Comment: Are you an admin? Do you have edit permissions for the project?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Screen schemes menu of the project settings check if the desired field, in this case Affects Version/s, is on the edit issue screen.

[image: Jira Project Configure Screens]

If it's absent, add it using the Select Field drop down menu at the bottom. Once the field is present you should be able to edit the field, either from the regular task view or the edit screen.

Comment: Since I could see the field just not edit it, it didn't cross my mind it could be a screen issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In JIRA there are three type of screen create, edit and display.

You are able to see the Affects Version/s field of an issue in JIRA but not able to edit it.

You are able to see it because this Affects Version/s field is present is display screen. Just check if it is present on edit screen also.

this kind of problem we face if any field is present is display screen but not in edit screen.